# Make the 'python' phrase refer to Python 3 on Linux?

Tags: python

So whenever I run `python -v` it says I'm using Python 2, why is `python` reserved for Python 2 on Ubuntu, and is there a way to make `python` reserve python 3? The latest version.

For example, Id prefer to write

```
`python /files/app.py`
```

To execute my files than write

```
`python3 /files/app.py`
```

It seems messy to have to add the 3, you don't on Windows, so why is Ubuntu different?

Comment: Ubuntu may uses Python2 to run some elements. If you assign Python3 to `python` then it may works incorrectly.

Comment: I have at the same time python, python2, python2.7, python3, python3.6, python3.7 and not so long time ago I had also python2.6, python3.5, python3.4. And the same with `pip`

Comment: You should use [virtual environments](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/). They solve that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alias to do this. Add the following line to your .bashrc:

```
alias python=python3
```

Don't forget to reopen your terminal, or do `source ~/.bashrc` for the changes to take effect.

Duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3?newreg=2d65244495254324b0964f4dc6f61867) post.

Ubuntu does this because you probably have two versions of Python installed, a system variant and a 3.x variant you are using. You can try `python --version` and `python3 --version` to see. If they return different things, you have two installations.

For example:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.3
$ alias python=python3
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

To circumvent the alias use the `command` built-in command:

```
$ command python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Another way to circumvent the alias is to use `\` before the command.

```
$ \python --version 
Python 2.7.6
```

To disable the alias in the current shell use the `unalias` built-in command:

```
$ unalias python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to get it to install a higher version with `sudo apt-get install python` ? Say 3.7 instead of 3.6.

Comment: @VoiDHD can you mark it as accepted? If you are using Anaconda, type `conda update --all` into your terminal and that will update it. You can also try `sudo apt-get install python 3.7`

Answer (score 0):

As already stated here, you have system python and user python and one option is to create aliases for python and pip on a user level ~/.bashrc

Another option is to create a virtual environment for each project you work on. The advantage of this is that you only install modules relevant to each project.

Create a virtual environment

```
mkdir someproject 
cd someproject/
python3 -m venv venv
```

Activate environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Check python and pip version

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from ~/someproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ python -V
Python 3.6.7
```

Deactivate environment

```
deactivate
```

Python, pip and any other modules you decide to install is installed in the venv folder instead of system wide.

Only gotcha is to remember to activate your environment.